# Show that $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle\cong \Bbb Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle\cong \Bbb Z[i]$.

Take the mapping $\phi :\Bbb Z[x]\to \Bbb Z[i]$ to be $\phi(f(x))=f(i)$ which is definitely a ring homomorphism.

Surely $\phi$ i ssurjective as $a+bi\in \Bbb Z[i]$ we have $f(x)=a+bx\in \Bbb Z[x]$

Then $\ker \phi=\{f(x):f(i)=0\}$
To show that $\ker \phi \cong \langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Now definitely $x^2+1\in \ker \phi\implies \langle x^2+1\rangle\subseteq \ker \phi$

Taking $f(x)\in \ker \phi\implies f(i)=0$.

**Unable to show that $f(x)\in \langle x^2+1\rangle$**.

Please help.

Comment: You seem to be *implicitly* using that irreducibles are prime in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ (or unique factorization or related results). That inference should be *explicitly* justified by citing the Theorem you are invoking. Further you should justify the irreducbility claim.  Often such exercises are designed to help you understand how such results do and don't generalize, so it is important to demonstrate *precise* understanding of such.

Comment: @BillDubuque; I only used the fact that we can't write $x^2+1$ as a product of lower degree polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$

Comment: I assume you are looking at the homomorphism $\phi \colon {\mathbb Z}[x] \mapsto {\mathbb Z}[i]$ given by $x \mapsto i$, i.e., $f(x) \mapsto f(i)$? The kernel of that map *is* $\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: @Magdiragdag; I explained where my problem is ;

Comment: @Magdiragdag;Can you help now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f (x)\in \Bbb Z [x] $ such that $f (i) =0$.
Since $x^2+1$ is monic there exists $q (x),r (x)\in\Bbb Z [x] $ such that $f (x)=(x^2+1)q (x)+r (x) $ and $r (x)= ax+b $ with $a,b\in \Bbb Z $.
Then $0=r (i)=ai+b$, thus $a=b=0$ hence $f (x)\in\langle x^2+1\rangle $.

Comment: How can you write that?? $\Bbb Z[x]$ is not a ED

Comment: @Maths_Student As long as the leading coefficient of the divisor is a unit (as it is in this case since $x^2 +1$ is monic), you can still divide.

Comment: Can't this be done without division algorithm?

Comment: Division algorithm holds whenever the divisor has unitary leading coefficient, as in this case. Thus my answer is correct, please remove downvote.